# Database that consumes less disk space

Tags: database, cassandra, relational-database, bigtable

I'm looking at solutions to store a massive quantity of information consuming the less possible disk space.

The information structure is very simple and the queries will also be very simple.
I've looked at solutions like Apache Cassandra and relations databases but couldn't find a comparison where disk usage is mentioned.

Any ideas on this would be great.

Comment: Just buy a bigger hard drive.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't really answer my question. I'm looking for way to optimize disk usage.

Comment: lol, that's actually a relevant point. How much data are we really talking about here? 10GB? 100GB? 1TB?

Comment: The goal is to deploy the database on a shared hosting site which has disk space limits. Increasing them has a serious impact on the monthly fee so it's not as easy as buying a new hard drive. It has impact on the fixed monthly cost of the solution.

Comment: Your question does not really provide enough information to answer.  How much data is a massive quanity?  How many writes a second do you anticipate?  Do you need low latency read access or will you be accessing items in batch?  What indexes will you need for retrieving the data later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a [look](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) at Oracle Berkeley DB - very simple robust  database (key/value):

"Berkeley DB enables the development of custom data management solutions, without the overhead traditionally associated with such custom projects. Berkeley DB provides a collection of well-proven building-block technologies that can be configured to address any application need from the handheld device to the datacenter, from a local storage solution to a world-wide distributed one, from kilobytes to petabytes."

Answer (score 3):

Speaking about Apache Cassandra - it's just a disk space hog. 200 MB of logs resulted in 1.2 GB files produced by Cassandra - and the keyspace was just 4 columns with 200 length strings.

Answer (score 2):

[Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) might worth a check if you can store your data in key-value

Answer (score 0):

Newest version of Microsoft's SQL Server (2008) supports several levels of compression (row compression and page compression, in addition to backup compression). Might be worth investigating.

Some relevant resources:

- [Linchi Shea shows that compression can sometimes *improve* performance](http://www2.sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2008/05/16/sql-server-2008-page-compression-performance-impact-on-table-scans.aspx)
- [Official MS Best Pracices doc for SQL 2008 compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894051.aspx)

Comment: Does compressed data stay in read/write mode ? MySQL also has data compression but all compressed data is readonly.

Comment: PostgreSQL also supports on the fly compression:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html